# How to create a step by step form with Phalcon in PHP

Tags: php, forms, phalcon

I'm currently working on a project using the Phalcon Framework that has pages with complex forms and a lot of inputs, to break it down nicely I'm dividing the forms into a step-by-step process.

How would one validate the form on each step before going to the next step and then save the whole form on the final step?

I can't seem to find anything documented about this sort of process as it likes to validate the form in it's entirety if I use the form builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just create a custom methods in your form class to validate any step, and the posted data from some step save into message class and store it into session by "stepX", when posted data is not valid just set defaults from post. When valid save it into session as i describe above.

For example how i mean "controller"

```
<?php
class MyController extends BaseController {
     public function processStep1Action(){
           $form = new MyForm();
           if($this->request->isPost()){//im using my custom request class 
              if(!$form->isValid($this->request->getPost()){
                  //error messages goes here
                  $form->setDefaultsFromRequest($this->request); // it will set the filled data
              }
              else {
                  $messageClass = new MyMessageContainer();
                  $messageClass->setData($this->request);//inside parse requested data into message class, or parse it as $messageClass->name = $this->request->getPost('name');

                  $this->session->save('step1',$messageClass); //maybe it would be want to serialize it
                  //then redirect to the step 2 or x

              }
           }
     }
}
```

So in the next step you can access data from sessions $this->session->get('step1'); so you can in final step load all posted data and store it into DB.

I hope this helps! :)

here is my form maybe it can be helpful for you.

```
<?php 

namespace Manager\Library\Forms\User;

use Phalcon\Forms\Form,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Email,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Select,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Password,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Check,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Confirmation,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\StringLength,
    Phalcon\Forms\Element\Submit,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf,
    Model\Group;

class AddUser extends Form {
    public function initialize()
    {
        $email = new Email('email');
        $email->addValidators(array(
            new \Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email(array(
            'message' => 'Nezadali jste email nebo má nesprávny tvar(email@domena.tld).'
            ))
        ));

                $this->add($email);

        $this->initGroupElement();

                $password = new Password('password');
        $password
            ->addValidator(new StringLength(array('min' => 6,'messageMinimum'   => 'Nezadali jste heslo nebo je příliš krátke, minimální počet znaků je 6.')))
            ->addValidator(new Confirmation(array('with'    => 'password-again',"message"   => "Zadané hesla se neshodují.")));
        $this->add($password);

        $repeatPassword = new Password('password-again');
        $this->add($repeatPassword);

                $this->initializeProfileElements();
                $active = new Check('active',array('value'  => 1));
                $this->add($active);
        $this->add( new Submit('save') );

                \Phalcon\Tag::setDefault('password', '');
                \Phalcon\Tag::setDefault('password-again', '');
    }

        public function initializeEdit(){
            $email = new Email('email');
        $email->addValidators(array(
            new \Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email(array(
            'message' => 'Nezadali jste email nebo má nesprávny tvar(email@domena.tld).'
            ))
        ));

                $this->add($email);

        $this->initGroupElement();

                $password = new Password('password');

        $this->add($password);

        $repeatPassword = new Password('password-again');
        $this->add($repeatPassword);

                $this->initializeProfileElements();
                $active = new Check('active',array('value' => 1));
                $this->add($active);
        $this->add( new Submit('save') );

                \Phalcon\Tag::setDefault('password', '');
                \Phalcon\Tag::setDefault('password-again', '');
        }

        protected function initGroupElement(){
            $auth = \Core\Auth::getIdentity();
            $groups = new Group();
//            $groups->addColumns(array('id','name'));
            //set global condition about Super Admin
            $groups->addFilter('id', 1,'<>');

            if($auth){
                //set restrictions for main groups
                if((int)$auth->group_id === 1){ //super admingroup
                    //no filter
                }
                else if((int)$auth->group_id === 2){ //admin group
                    $groups->addFilter('id', 1,'>');
                }
                else if((int)$auth->group_id === 6){//Provozovatel group
                    $groups->addFilter('id',array(3,6,7));
                    $groups->addFilter('public', 1,'=',true);
                }
                else { // other groups
                    $groups->addFilter('public', 1);
                }
            }

            $groups = $groups->findFiltered();
            $groupElement = new Select('group');
            foreach($groups as $group){
                $groupElement->addOption(array($group->id => $group->name));
            }

            $this->add($groupElement);

        }

        protected function initializeProfileElements(){
            $forename = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('forename');
            $this->add($forename);
            $surname = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('surname');
            $this->add($surname);
            $street = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('street');
            $this->add($street);
            $postal = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('postal');
            $this->add($postal);
            $city = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('city');
            $this->add($city);
            $ic = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('ic');
            $this->add($ic);
            $dic = new \Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('dic');
            $this->add($dic);
        }

        public function setDefault($fieldName,$value){
            \Phalcon\Tag::setDefault($fieldName, $value);
        }

        public function setDefaults($object){
            if($object instanceof \Model\User){
                $this->setDefaultsFromObject($object);
            }
            else if($object instanceof \Phalcon\Http\Request){
                $this->setDefaultsFromRequest($object);
            }
        }

        protected function setDefaultsFromObject(\Model\User $user){
            $profile = $user->getRelated('\Model\Profile');   
            \Phalcon\Tag::setDefaults(array(
                'email'     => $user->email,
                'group'     => $user->group_id,
                'active'    => $user->active,
                'forename'  => $profile->forename,
                'surname'   => $profile->surname,
                'street'    => $profile->street,
                'city'      => $profile->city,
                'postal'    => $profile->postal,
                'ic'        => $profile->IC,
                'dic'       => $profile->DIC
            ));
        }

        protected function setDefaultsFromRequest(\Phalcon\Http\Request $request){
            \Phalcon\Tag::setDefaults(array(
                    'email'     => $request->getPost('email'),
                    'group'     => $request->getPost('group'),
                    'active'    => $request->getPost('active')
             ));

            \Phalcon\Tag::setDefaults(array(
                'forename'  => $request->getPost('forename'),
                'surname'   => $request->getPost('surname'),
                'street'    => $request->getPost('street'),
                'city'      => $request->getPost('city'),
                'postal'    => $request->getPost('postal'),
                'ic'        => $request->getPost('ic'),
                'dic'       => $request->getPost('dic')
            ));
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post @Kamil, but wouldn't $form-isValid($this->request->getPost()) throw errors on step 1 because step 2 fields that are required aren't available as they haven't been entered yet?

Comment: As i said, you must have, defined custom methods for rendering any step you will not use initialize function for that, for example for the step 1: $form = new MyForm(); $form->initializeStep1(); and inside is just validation of all elements for step1 so it will be right if you will call ->isValid for the step1 :)

Comment: I think I get what you're saying I will give that a go tomorrow as done too much today and will mark this as the answer if it works. I already had the idea of saving the steps to the session but wasn't sure on the validation side. Thanks either way for a step in the right direction :)

Comment: Be sure that it will be work :) and you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kamil's answer, another option to consider is to use Javascript on the front-end to handle your multi-step form. This will add some complexity as you will need to have the javascript to handle the form steps and do preliminary validation, but it only requires a single submit where you can validate content within a single method.

Comment: I ended up doing something along the lines of @Kamil's answer. If a Form created using Phalcon's Form Builder has more than 1 step it's separated out into step functions. This seemed like to most viable solution and is doing what we need it to.